# How does FOLLOW work for the following CFG?

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

The original cfg is

```
S -> S + S | SS | (S) | S* | a
```

After refactoring and eliminating left recursion, I arrive at the following reduction:

```
S -> TB
B -> AB | e
A -> +S | TB | *
T -> (S) | a
```

When calculating `follow(B)`, online sources that I can find say that it should be {$}.  However, based on the rules in the dragon book, it looks like `follow(B) = follow(S) + follow(A)`, because of rule 3 (a production `A -> aB` causes everything in `follow(A)` to be in `follow(B)`.

Am I understanding the rule incorrectly?

Comment: Citation for the (incorrect) claim that FOLLOW(B) is `{$}`?

Comment: http://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/~jiangli/teaching/CS308/CS308-slides03.pdf

Comment: On a different note I'm trying to teach myself compilers and i was wondering if you have any advice.  I'm currently self studying my way through the dragon book.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Those class notes are erroneous

Comment: A SO comment is too brief for the advice I'd really like to give, so I'll leave you with some abridged advice: don't spend too much time learning how parser generators work. Don't spend any time on LL parser generators. Don't spend any time on badly documented parser generators. Learn how to use some mature, well-documented generator capable of handling most useful grammars; at least an LALR(1) generator and a GLR or GLL generator if you can find one for your implementation language. Don't write a calculator. FIgure out how to create an AST. Then start compiling.

Comment: In other words, focus on what grammars are used for, not how they work under the hood. Just like when you learn how to do computer graphics, you need to know how to use trig functions; you don't need to know how to evaluate a Taylor series (although at some point you might find it interesting).

Comment: And for anyone else cruising by later, the above was 100% my opinion, which is why it's not in an answer. I have no intention of defending my opinions here, and will delete the comments upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your internet source is wrong. Your understanding of the FOLLOW algorithm is fine (and also appears in the class notes you are quoting).

It's actually an odd example for an exercise in parsing, since the grammar is ambiguous. Refactoring and left-recursion elimination do not remove ambiguity; the end result is still ambiguous, and ambiguous grammars will always have parsing conflicts.